# Can't ssh into machine after running a program

Tags: ssh

I was ssh'd into a machine and ran a program. The program seemed to freeze my machine and kicked me off/closed my connection. I have been trying to ssh into it ever since but am timing out.

Comment: Lots of possibilities. Is the machine up (can you ping it)? If not the system might have crashed with being out of memory (OOM) corrupting the file system so the machine isn't booting. Is the machine on a fixed IP address? If not the machine might have rebooted and been given a different address. Do you have a way to reboot the machine remotely? Can you get to the console remotely?

Comment: I can't ping it. I am getting timeouts. I suspect the machine crashed. I'm not sure how to reboot or get to the machine remotely if it is off.

Comment: Is it a physical machine or a virtual machine? If it's bare metal, where does it physically reside? If it's a virtual machine, is it being run by a cloud provider? If so, which one? Please edit your question to include as much information as you can about the machine and the program you ran.